# ASP.NET Execute local application from server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a system that have to use a Identification Card Reader.
The Identification Card Reader application is installed on the local computer. This application is used to retrieve data from Card Reader to the system. 
I can run the Identification Card Reader on the local computer using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\MyKadDev2\MyKad.exe")
```

However, when the system is being publish to the server, the system cannot retrieve the Identification Card Reader application that is installed on the local computer. How I want to execute and run local apps on the system that run on server.

I am using ASP.NET VB.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\MyKadDev2\MyKad.exe")
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(11000)
Dim FILENAME As String = Server.MapPath("mykaddata.txt")
Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
objStreamReader = File.OpenText(FILENAME)
Dim contents As String = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
txtIC_No.Text = contents.Split(ControlChars.Tab)(0)
txtName.Text = contents.Split(ControlChars.Tab)(1)
objStreamReader.Close()
```

Comment: You'll need to run some sort of program on the client machine that communicates back to the server.

Comment: Can you help to define more on _sort of program on the client machine_ ??

Comment: You need to create a program that runs on the client machine that is not subject to the same sandboxing restrictions as a webpage in a browser. You can't just access hardware at will from a webpage in a browser, can you imagine the security implications of that?